# How to remove image resize handle in ckeditor image2 (enhancedimage)

Tags: ckeditor

I have managed to remove the dialog boxes allowing an image to be resized (in ckeditor image2 plugin). Is there a way to prevent the user from resizing an image with the corner handle?

EDIT:

Reinmar is right. And to use in config.js do:

`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  ...
  config.disallowedContent = 'img[width,height]';
}`

This will also remove the height and width options from the dialog box in a functional way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's satisfactory for you to remove `width` and `height` attributes at all use:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    disallowedContent: 'img[width,height]'
} );
```

You can read more about [disallowed content here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) and the [Advanced Content Filter here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

If you want to hide only resizer but leave inputs in the image dialog and attrubtes in code, then I believe you need to hide it via CSS.

Comment: I tried adding

`config.disallowedContent = 'img[width]';`

to the following function in my config.js

`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {...`

but it doesn't seem to have any effect. 
Perhaps width and height are allowed because of the image2 plugin?

Comment: Disallowed content was introduced in CKEditor 4.4. Maybe you use older version? And disallowed content has higher priority than allowed content, so you can override what other features enable. I checked that code and it worked.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I had only just downloaded it so thought I had a recent version, but it was bundled with a Statamic plugin and slightly older. Thanks!